# Aurelia: always call method in the view (problems after upgrade)

Tags: javascript, aurelia

We've upgraded Aurelia (in particular `aurelia-framework` to `1.0.6`, `aurelia-bindong` to `1.0.3`) and now we're facing some binding issues.

There's a list of elements with computed classes, and we had a method int the custom element that contained the  list:

```
getClass(t) {
    return '...' + 
           (this.selected.indexOf(t) !== -1
                ? 'disabled-option' :
                : ''
           ) + (t === this.currentTag 
                ? 'selected-option' 
                : ''
           );
}
```

And `class.one-way="$parent.getClass(t)"` for the list element, everything was OK.

After the upgrade it simply stopped to work, so whenever the `selected` (btw it's bindable) or `currentTag` properties were modified, the `getClass` method just wasn't called.

I partially solved this by moving this logic to the view:

```
class="${$parent.getClass(t) + (selected.indexOf(t) !== -1 ? 'disabled-option' : '') (t === $parent.currentTag ? 'selected-option' : '')}"
```

I know that looks, well... bad, but that made `t === $parent.currentTag` work, but the `disabled-option` class still isn't applied.

So, the question is:

### How do I force Aurelia to call methods in attributes in the view?

#### P.S.

I understand that it might cause some performance issues.

#### Small note:

I can not simply add a `selected` attribute to the list element since I don't to somehow modify the data that comes to the custom element and I basically want my code to work properly without making too many changes.

## UPD

<del>I ended up with [this awesome solution by Fabio Luz](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34499658/2044039) with this small edit:</del>

**UPD** Here's a way to interpret [this awesome solution by Fabio Luz](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34499658/2044039).

```
export class SelectorObjectClass {
    constructor(el, tagger){
        Object.assign(this, el);
        this.tagger = tagger;
    }

    get cssClass(){
        //magic here
    }
}
```

and

```
this.shown = this.shown(e => new SelectorObjectClass(e, this));
```

But I ended up with [this (defining an extra array)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34534267/2044039).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use a property instead of a function. Like this:

```
//pay attention at the "get" before function name
get getClass() {
    //do your magic here
    return 'a b c d e';
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class.bind="getClass"></div>
```

**EDIT**

I know that it might be an overkill, but it is the nicest solution I found so far:

Create a class for your objects:

```
export class MyClass {
   constructor(id, value) {
      this.id = id;
      this.value = value;
   }

   get getClass() {
      //do your magic here
      return 'your css classes';
   }
}
```

Use the above class to create the objects of the array:

```
let shown = [];
shown[1] = new MyClass('someId', 'someValue');
shown[2] = new MyClass('someId', 'someValue');
```

Now, you will be able to use `getClass` property:

```
<div repeat.for="t of shown" class.bind="t.getClass">...</div>
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: But I need to pass the selected element as an argument (preferably)

Comment: Can't you create the property "inside" the argument object?

Comment: I actually have ``<div repeat.for="t of shown" class="{stuff I posted that depends on t}">...</div>``, so I'm not sure how would I pass that t to the getter.

Comment: what is "shown"? is an array of objects? ints? strings?

Comment: ``shown`` is an array o objects. I just want to find a way to update the class depending on the ``selected`` (array of objects). Classes are computed for each element of the list.

Comment: Something like angular dirty checking or whatever

Comment: those objects have a "class" declaration? show the code you use for creating the array

Comment: No, these objects are just javascrtipt objects like ``{value: "Bob", id: 45}``, there's a ``@bindable shown`` and I just pass an array of objects to the custom element I'm having issues with :)

Comment: Magnificent! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It looks pretty sad.

I miss understand your point for computing class in html. Try that code, it should help you.

```
computedClass(item){
  return `
     ${this.getClass(item)}
     ${~selected.indexOf(item) ? 'disabled-option': ''}
     ${item === this.currentTag ? 'selected-option' : ''}
  `;
}
```

Your code not working cause you miss else option at first if state :/

**Update:**
To toggle attribute state try `selected.bind="true/false"`

Good luck,
Egor

Comment: Sorry, I just made a typo posting the question here 'cause I removed some stuff from the original code

Comment: try selected.bind="true/false" to toggle attribute

Comment: As it was mentioned in the original question (**Small note** at the end), I would rather not use the state variable

Comment: is there smth special in Aurelia fpr methods starting from ``computed``? Because if not, then it's what we had before and it didn't work :(

Comment: Aurelia have `computed` properties, they looks like plain functions http://eisenbergeffect.bluespire.com/aurelia-computed/ . As I see you try to dive up the river :)

Comment: But it's not a property, it's a function

Answer (score 1):

A great solution was offered by [Fabio](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34499658/2044039) but it caused issues (the data that was two-way bound to the custom element (result of the selection) wasn't of the same type as the input and so on). This definitely can be fixed but it would take a *significant* amount of time and result in rewriting tests, etc. Alternatively, yeah, we could put the original object as some property blah-blah-blah...

#### Anyway:

There's another solution, less elegant but much faster to implement.

1. Let's declare an extra array

   ```
   @bindable shownProperties = [];
   ```
2. Inject `ObserverLocator`
3. Observe the selected array

   ```
   this.obsLoc.getArrayObserver(this.selected)
       .subscribe(() => this.selectedArrayChanged);
   ```
4. Update the `shownProperties`

   ```
   isSelected(t) {
       return this.selected.indexOf(t) !== -1;
   }

   selectedArrayChanged(){
       for(var i = 0; i < this.shown.length; i++){
           this.shownProperties[i] = {
               selected: this.isSelected(this.shown[i])
           }
       }
   }
   ```
5. And, finally, in the view:

   ```
   class="... ${shownProperties[$index].selected ? 'disabled-option' : '')} ..."
   ```

### So, the moral of the story:

Don't use methods in the view like I did :)